# How to determine if an expression member is of a collection type and then iterate over that collection?

Tags: c#, lambda

example classes:

```
public class Procedure: SomeBaseClass
{
     public Guid Id {get;set;}
     public ICollection<Task> Tasks {get;set;}

}

public class Task: SomeBaseClass
{
     public Guid Id {get;set;}
     public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Method to take in expression colelction:

```
public viod DoSomethingWithProperties<T>(Guid enittyId, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] propertiesToDoStuffWith) where T: SomeBaseClass
{
   var item = someService<T>().FindById(entityId);
   .......

   foreach(var expression in propertiesToDoStuffWith)
   {
     ///I need to iterate the propertiesToDetach and determine if the property is a collection so I can perform operations on each item.
   }

}
```

I may call it like this:

```
DoSomethingWithProperties<Procedure>(1111-1111-1111-1111-1111,p => p.tasks);
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a normal delegate, not an expression tree.

Comment: Shouldnt that be `foreach(var expression in propertiesToDoStuffWith(item))`?

Comment: @ChrisShain, i think you are correct. My only issue is that the expressions are an array of properties for that type. Would I still want to cast that expression tree? I am thinking yes, but would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine the `type` after you compile your `Expression` by using the `is` keyword.

```
foreach(var expression in propertiesToDoStuffWith)
{
     var result = expression.Compile()(item);

     if (result is ICollection){
          // handle collection type
     }
     else {
          // some other type
     }
}
```

Comment: You need to call the delegate.